# How to add custom JNDI resources into wildfly-10 similar like <custom-resource> of glassfish server?

Tags: server, jboss, glassfish, redhat, wildfly-10

This is the code which is use to add custom resources in glassfish server but my requirement is to achieve this in wildfly-10 server but i don't know how to do it,so please help me with this

```
<custom-resource
factory-class="org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PropertiesFactory" res- 
type="java.util.Properties" jndi-name="docdokuplm.config">
<property name="codebase" value="http://localhost:9001"></property>
<property name="vaultPath" value="/var/lib/docdoku"></property>
</custom-resource>
<custom-resource 
factory-class="org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PropertiesFactory" res- 
type="java.util.Properties" jndi-name="auth.config">
<property name="basic.header.enabled" value="true"></property>
<property name="session.enabled" value="true"></property>
<property name="jwt.key" value="singh20111995"></property>
<property name="jwt.enabled" value="true"></property>
</custom-resource>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried to read wildfly documentation but they have not mentioned anything about adding custom resources as JNDI, i referred some blogs also in which they have given how to migrate from glassfish to wildfly but it was of no use for me

Comment: can anyone help me on this,it is bit urgent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
        <bindings>
            <object-factory name="java:/docdokuplm.config" module="net.flexoptix.jbossTools" class="net.flexoptix.jbossTools.PropertiesFactory">
                <environment>
                    <property name="vaultPath" value="/var/lib/docdoku"/>
                    <property name="codebase" value="http://localhost:8080"/>
                </environment>
            </object-factory>
```

you can add subsystem to add custom JNDI in wildfly.

Comment: if you want to add multiple properties then in same subsystem you can add <object-factory> with different JNDI name